# C# OOPS clarification

Tags: c#

Please why line "b[0]= new Child2();" fails at runtime and not at compile time. Please don't check the syntax, i just did it here

```
class Base
{}

class Child1 : Base
{}

class Child2 : Base
{}

class Test
{
   void Main()
   {
     Base [] b= new Child1[10];
     b[0]= new Child2(); <-- Fails at runtime but not at compile time WHY?
   }
}
```

Comment: consider this msdn article [Array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I believe its runtime not compile time as at compile time, b's value is still its default value. The same way it doesn't know  if b has a 0 element

Comment: What is OOPS? Where did the S come from

Comment: [Eric Lippert's blog explains this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ilya Ivanov is right: An array of Child1 objects can be cast to an array of Base objects. But you cannot add a Child2 to this, as this is a different class.

[Array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) means that if two classes have a subclass - superclass relationship, their arrays also have this relationship.

Answer (score 5):

```
new Child1[10];
```

You've just declared a new array of type `Child1`.

```
b[0]= new Child2();
```

Now you're attempting to put a **sibling** class, into it. An array of objects can store that object, and it's subclasses, but can not store it's siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You defined b as array of child1, then are trying to insert a child2.

However the compiler cannot what you assigned to b, as anything could happen between the two lines. At runtime however, it can be determined.